# Can you use multiple selectors for @e[type=!entity]?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If I can, Using the type=! Or, everything except selector, can I exclude multiple entities? My code is /execute @e[type=lightning_bolt] summon lightning_bolt. I also want to exclude the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1.12 no, in 1.13 yes.

This is something that can easily be tested by just trying it.

Comment: Do i just use [type=!Lightning_bolt,Player]? or do i put a ! for both?

Comment: That could have been your main question. Comma separates, so you need type= again. And you can use Google for that.